# What is the difference between simple and source set dependencies when working with the Kotlin MPP plugin?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm using the Kotlin MPP plugin (with `.kts` support) and while I've been reading some code I came upon `build.gradle.kts` files like this:

```
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                api(kotlinxCollectionsImmutable)
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        with(Libs) {
            commonMainApi(kotlinStdLibCommon)
            commonMainApi(kotlinxCoroutinesCommon)
        }
    }
}
```

What is the difference between declaring an `api` dependency within a `sourceSet` compared to declaring a `commonMainApi` dependency? Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference. The commonMainApi is just an alternative way of doing the same, and doesn't look to be recommended any more. Link - https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html

> Альтернативным способом указания зависимостей является использование
>   встроенного DSL Gradle на верхнем уровне с именами конфигурации,
>   следующими за шаблоном : [translation:
>   Alternatively, dependencies can be declared by specifying
>   configuration names at the top level using the built-in Gradle DSL]

```
dependencies {
    commonMainApi 'com.example:foo-common:1.0'
    jvm6MainApi 'com.example:foo-jvm6:1.0'
}
```

Interestingly, this document is described as a translation of https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html where this paragraph (about the alternative syntax) is completely missing, so one can only deduce that the English version has been updated and the alternative syntax removed as either not recommended or obsolete at this point.

Comment: So which one is obsolete?

Comment: the flat one, commonMainApi - however, that's my interpretation based on what I explained above - only JetBrains can tell you for sure if its obsolete or not. But I can add - I don't see anyone using it, everyone I know is using commonMain-dependencies-api

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick to the one you suggested. It makes more sense anyway.